# Are the phases of the induced current (eddy currents) in a thin sheet uniform?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, electromagnetic-induction

I have implemented a 2D finite difference method to compute the eddy currents induced by an AC magnetic field (homogeneous, oscillating at a fixed frequency) in a conductive thin sheet. Typically, the thickness of the sheet is around the half of the skin depth.  Ultimately, the intent is to compute the impact the sheet on the global magnetic field.

The result surprised me: it appears that the phase of the induced current is not uniform over the surface of the sheet. The consequence is that the magnetic field answered by the sheet is not a standard oscillating field: at a given position in space, the direction of the answered field describes an ellipse.

I have two questions :

- is this phenomenon physically possible ?
- is this phenemenon a usual computation artifact related to finite difference problem solving ?

Thank you by advance for your help.